# Working with encrypted data in travis

Tags: web-services, encryption, travis-ci

I've made a web-service and I'm working with sensitive data that I want to encrypt (a yandel key). I have this data in the path `src/main/resources/application.properties` with the content `yandex.api_key=valueOfMyKey`.

I execute the command `travis encrypt-file application.properties` and get the file encoded `application.properties.enc`. In addition, I get this output, and I realize what it's said (I add the build script to my `.travis.yml`)

```
storing secure env variables for decryption
Please add the following to your build script (before_install stage in your .travis.yml, for instance):

openssl aes-256-cbc -K $encrypted_b21eaa919621_key -iv $encrypted_b21eaa919621_iv -in application.properties.enc -out application.properties -d

Pro Tip: You can add it automatically by running with --add.

Make sure to add application.properties.enc to the git repository.
Make sure not to add application.properties to the git repository.
Commit all changes to your .travis.yml.
```

I execute the command `travis lint .travis.yml` and I get a valid output. My travis file has now this content:

```
language: java
jdk:
- oraclejdk8
before_install:
- openssl aes-256-cbc -K $encrypted_b21eaa919621_key -iv $encrypted_b21eaa919621_iv
  -in src/main/resources/application.properties.enc -out src/main/resources/application.properties -d
```

However, I don't pass the travis test. I get the following output:

[image]

You can check my code in [this public repo](https://github.com/Santi-7/big-ws).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. I didn't activate travis before the encrypt of my file, so travis didn't have both values. I just activated it and did the encrypt again.